# How to load page inside ng-view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have ng-repeat list and ng-view:

```
<div ng-controller="TabCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="tab in tabs">
            <a href="#/{{tab.page}}">{{tab.title}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
     <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

routeProvider:

```
angular.module("sampleApp", ['ngRoute'], 
function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

    .when('', {
        templateUrl: 'tabs/main.html',
        controller: MainCtrl
    })
    .when('/main', {
        templateUrl: 'tabs/main.html',
        controller: MainCtrl
    })

    .when('/main/model/:url', {
        templateUrl: 'tabs/modelPage.html',
        controller: modelCtrl
    })
});
```

main.html:

```
<div>
<h1>Main</h1>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="model in models">
        <a href="#/main/model/{{model.url}}">{{model.name}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div ng-include="content"></div>
```

and controller MainCtrl:

```
function MainCtrl($scope, $location, $http){
$scope.content = "main_main.html";
$http.post('get_data.php', {action: 'get_models'})
.success(function(data){
    $scope.models = angular.fromJson(data);
});
```

}

I want to get modelPage.html instead of main.html, but ng-view not work for this. How to realize this code?

Comment: In what directory the file is located main_main.html?

Answer (score 0):

I may not be understanding your question right, but it seems that you are missing a 'modelCtrl' controller in your JS (or it's just not shown in your question details).

**Your $routeProvider**

```
angular.module("sampleApp", ['ngRoute'], 
function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

    ...

    .when('/main/model/:url', {
        templateUrl: 'tabs/modelPage.html',
        controller: modelCtrl
    })
});
```

**Add 'modelCtrl'**

```
function modelCtrl($scope, $location, $http){
    ...
});
```